# Validate input type=file with onBlur

Tags: javascript, validation, onblur, input-type-file

I'm able to use onBlur to validate type=text or textarea inputs, however I haven't been able to get the same to work for type=file.

This works:

```
<input type='text' name='sometextfield' size=30 class='input' onBlur="alert('Frell me dead, it works!');"
```

This does not (no error):

```
  <input type='file' name='file_upload' size=30 class='input' onBlur="alert('Frell me dead, it works!');">
```

What is the trick to validating type=file input boxes, on the fly?  I'd like to do this in vanilla Javascript.  I'm testing with Chrome 17.0.963.56 and Firefox 10.0.2 under Ubuntu.

Thanks for tips/pointers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try using the onchange-Event:

```
<input type="file" name="file_upload" size="30" class="input" onchange="alert('Frell me dead, it works!');">
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TimWolla/azvGP/

Comment: I feel such an idiot...there I was trying with [some crazy pseudo-blur thing](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/Yhsch/), and I forgot all about `onchange`. Sigh... +1! =)

Comment: Thanks so much, also forgot about onChange!