# jQuery 'blur' event not working for file field

Tags: jquery

I have form which saves the record on each field blur event but whenever I select a file for file field it saves the record which is wrong as I expect it should work on 'blur' event only.

Code :

```
jQuery(document).on("blur", ":input[type!='button']", function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```

It gives me alert on the selection of field value. All other input types working fine with this event.

HTML Code :

```
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
        <label id="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_FirstName-lbl" for="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_FirstName">
    First Name</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="text" name="jform[com_tjucm_test-for-draft_FirstName]" id="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_FirstName" value="" aria-invalid="false">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
        <label id="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_New-lbl" for="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_New">
    Image</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <input type="file" name="jform[com_tjucm_test-for-draft_New]" id="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_New" size="32" accept=".png,.jpeg,.jpg" class="validate-filetype"><br>
    Maximum upload size: <strong>32.00 MB</strong>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-sm-4 control-label">
        <label id="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_CalendarField-lbl" for="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_CalendarField">
    Calendar Field</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="field-calendar">
        <div class="input-append">
            <input type="text" id="jform_com_tjucm_test_for_draft_CalendarField" name="jform[com_tjucm_test-for-draft_CalendarField]" value="" class="calendar-textfield-class" data-alt-value="" autocomplete="off">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you show your HTML

Comment: is this something are you looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9607354/validate-input-type-file-with-onblur

Comment: it's working for me http://jsfiddle.net/mdogtnja/ please create the jsfiddle link.

Comment: just remove the : (colon) before input the code like in fidel "input[type!='button']" here no colon is given .But you put a colon

Comment: @YaseenAhmad : try by adding input type file & it gives alert on file selection instead of showing alert on 'blur' event

Comment: @executable added HTML code

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

```
jQuery(document).on("blur", "input:not([type='button'])", function() {
    alert('hi');
});
```